# Auto layout issue on iOS 11 when selecting different devices in Storyboard Device Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11

I'm using Xcode 9.0 and have come across an auto layout issue when my app runs in iOS 11. I'm currently testing my app on an iPhone 6S.  In Storyboard if I select iPhone X, 8+, or an iPad in the Device Bar, my subviews are not laid out properly.  However if I select iPhone 8 in the Device Bar, all subviews are laid out as expected on all devices including the iPhone X simulator.  I did not have this issue in iOS 10. While I do change some constraints in code based on the device the app runs on, I have made no device specific changes in Stoyboard and have not added any trait variations.  I tried unchecking the trait variations attribute in the view controller, but this had no effect.  My understanding of the Device Bar in Storyboard was that it just gives you a preview of how your view controllers look on each device based on the constraints you set, but it appears to actually be effecting how the views are laid out on each device (only on iOS 11 though). Does this sound like a bug or is my understanding of the device bar incorrect?

Comment: if you could add any screen shot of the constraints and the controller it would be much easy to understand.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue. I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: Never figured out why selecting different devices in the storyboard device bar (which to my understanding is only for generating previews) exhibited different behavior when running in the simulator. Possibly a bug in Xcode. But I believe my issue ended up being that I was trying to resize the frame of a subview's subview before the viewDidLayoutSubviews method had been called.  If you're using auto layout and you're trying to resize any frames make sure you do it after subviews have been laid out.

Comment: The same problem here.